# Two listeners for one event?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, events, actionlistener

I am trying to create a file according to two events: 
the first is a `JRadioButton`: according to which radio button is selected, the file will be saved in the respective folder, the second event is the "add" button. I am struggling with creating the file in the right folder, so far I managed to create the file in the right folder when the radio button is selected, but that is not what I want.

How can I create the file at the right moment (when "add" button is pressed) according to the previously selected radio button?

Things like:

```
if(e.getSource() == button && e.getActionCommand() == jradio1)
```

Doesn't work and neither deos nested if.

I think I'm missing the big picture, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a object that stores the location (possibly a String containing the filepath) of where you want the file, and which will update when you click on a given jradiobutton.

When you click the add button, you can then reference the same object to see where you should put the file.

Answer (score 0):

Selected radio and the event that is fired when you select the radio button are two different thing.

From what you have have stated is that you want to create the file on click of the add button.

Do this

1. You can just ignore the event fired on the radio selection.
2. When the event is fired on the press of the Add button, read the state of the
   radio and save the file

You can keep the instance of the radio class wide so that you can read it in the event handler for the button listener.

Comment: Also please share the code that you are using in detail. More appropriate suggestion can be made after reading your code.

Comment: *"please share the code that you are using in detail"* Please don't ask this of an OP, or they'll be dumping 600+ lines of code in SO or linking to their project on Github. Best to ask for a [mre].

Comment: Yes that was the intention

Comment: Note that `[mre]` in a comment auto-expands to [mre]. Not only shorter, but much more useful than asking for *"code .. in detail"*.

Comment: Great to know. Thanks @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 0):

Just use the name of the Radio button as the action command.  Same for the Add button.  When the radio button is selected, it saves its name as the target location.  Here is an example of how it can work.

```java
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class SavingFiles extends JPanel {

       String selectedLocation = null;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SavingFiles().start());
       }
       public void start() {

          String[] fileLocations =
                { "f:/location1", "c:/location2", "G:/location3"
                }; // etc

          int nRadioButtons = fileLocations.length;

          int defaultLoc = 0;
          YourActionListener listener = new YourActionListener();
          ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
          for (int i = 0; i < nRadioButtons; i++) {
             if (i == defaultLoc) {
                selectedLocation = fileLocations[i];
             }
             JRadioButton button =
                   new JRadioButton(fileLocations[i], i == defaultLoc);
             group.add(button);

             button.addActionListener(listener);
             // do something with button
             // store it or add it to panel.
             add(button);
          }

          JButton addButton = new JButton("Add"); // also acts as actionCommand
          addButton.addActionListener(listener);
          add(addButton);

          // Boiler plate
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("SavingFiles");
          frame.add(this);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 80));
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
       }

       // Note that if actionCommand is not set, then the button name
       // serves the same function.
       private class YourActionListener implements ActionListener {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
             String actionCommand = ev.getActionCommand();
             if (actionCommand.equals("Add")) {
                // add file to 'selectedLocation'
                System.out.println("adding file to " + selectedLocation);
             }
             else {
                selectedLocation = actionCommand;
                System.out.println("Location set to " + selectedLocation);
             }
          }
       }

    }
```